# SQL Server - query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables like this:

```
DECLARE @OpenTickets TABLE 
(
    [Month] SMALLINT
    ,[Year] SMALLINT
    ,[TotalOpen] INT
    ,UserDepartmentID SMALLINT
)

INSERT INTO @OpenTickets 
VALUES(11, 2014, 201,36), (11, 2014, 677, 106)


DECLARE @ResolveTickets TABLE 
(
    [Month] SMALLINT
    ,[Year] SMALLINT
    ,[TotalResolved] INT
    ,UserDepartmentID SMALLINT
    ,AVR INT
)

INSERT INTO @ResolveTickets 
VALUES(11, 2014, 202, 36, 2855), (11, 2014, 591, 106, 1990)

select * from @OpenTickets
select * from @ResolveTickets
```

I want to final output like

```
Month  Year  UserDepartmentID  TotalOpen  TotalResolved   AVR
----------------------------------------------------------------
11     2014      36               201       202           2855
11     2014      106              677       106           1990
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN`:

```
select a.*, b.TotalResolved, b.AVR 
from   @OpenTickets a inner join 
 @ResolveTickets b on a.UserDepartmentID = b.UserDepartmentID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the tables on the `UserDepartmentID` ...

```
select op.[Month],
op.[Year],
op.UserDepartmentID, 
TotalOpen, 
TotalResolved, 
AVR  
from @OpenTickets op inner join @ResolveTickets rt 
on op.UserDepartmentID = rt.UserDepartmentID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join. You will join both tables on unique ID of your department (`UserDepartmentID`) and you will get all the information from both tables that have this `UserDepartmentID`.

Query will look like :

```
select a.*, b.TotalResolved, b.AVR 
from @OpenTickets a 
join @ResolveTickets b on a.UserDepartmentID = b.UserDepartmentID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
select OpenTickets.Month, OpenTickets.Year, OpenTickets.UserDepartmentID, OpenTickets.TotalOpen, ResolveTickets.TotalResolved, ResolveTickets.AVR
from OpenTickets 
inner join ResolveTickets 
on (OpenTickets.UserDepartmentID  = ResolveTickets.UserDepartmentID 
&& OpenTickets.Year = ResolveTickets.Year
&& OpenTickets.Month= ResolveTickets.Month)
```

I have joined the two tables by UserDepartmentID, Year and Month.

Of course this solution is not complete because the constraints of the data are not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT o.Month,
       o.Year,
       o.UserDepartmentID,
       o.TotalOpen,
       r.TotalResolved,
       r.AVR
FROM   @OpenTickets o
       JOIN @ResolveTickets r
         ON o.Month = r.Month
            AND o.Year = r.Year
            AND o.UserDepartmentID = r.UserDepartmentID
```

You can join both the tables by matching `month` , `year` and `userdepartmentID`